# How to resize the user control in wpf at runtime

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, user-controls, wpf-controls

Am newbie to wpf development.In my wpf app i used **user control**.what i need is in runtime how can **resize the user control**,

Please help me to find solution,if my approach is wrong please guide me to get solution,

My XAML code is

```
<UserControl x:Class="test.pad"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Focusable="True" OverridesDefaultStyle="False">

    <Grid Width="102" Height="123" Name="Grid1" MouseMove="Grid1_MouseMove" MouseUp="Grid1_MouseUp" MouseDown="Grid1_MouseDown">
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="tt"/>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>

        <Border BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="2">

            <Canvas Height="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,1,0,0" Name="canvas1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                <RichTextBox Height="98" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,24,0,0" Name="richTextBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" BorderThickness="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="#FFFF96D8" Canvas.Top="-3" Canvas.Left="-1" />
                <Button BorderBrush="#FFFF96D8" Canvas.Left="46" Canvas.Top="-2" Height="23" Name="close" Width="27">

                </Button>
                <Button Height="23" Name="minimise" Width="27" BorderBrush="#FFFF96D8" Click="button1_Click" Canvas.Left="72" Canvas.Top="-2" ClipToBounds="False" IsEnabled="True" IsHitTestVisible="True" OverridesDefaultStyle="False" ForceCursor="False" Foreground="Black" MouseMove="button1_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="button1_MouseLeave">

            </Canvas>

        </Border>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

thanks 
ash

Comment: There is no usercontrol in this xaml

Comment: @Robert - It was there, just not formatted correctly :-)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `Height` and `Width` of the `UserControl` and also the `Grid`.
Set the `Margin` or `Size` Property for `UserControl` where you call it.

Comment: If i am using WPF user control in windows form Host in windows form then i can set the size at constructor but if i change the size of it during the program execution or in mid or in some condition then the size will not change at that time because control is already created. So this solution is beneficial if you are not updating during some condition.